# How to access ViewDataDictionary inside ExecuteResultAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

### Intro

I'm trying to decorate `Action - ViewResult` within use of extension method. The goal is be able to set `ViewData` within use of Decorator, outside of `Controller`. However, I am able to access only `TempData` whereas I would like to access `ViewData` inside of method `ExecuteResultAsync`.

### Question

> How to access ViewData from ExecuteResultAsync within use of accessing to  ActionContext? Is this the following
>   scenario at all possible?

### Scenario

**So instead of writing the following:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword()
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Change Password";
    return PartialView("_ChangePasswordPartial",...);
}
```

**I am trying to make it work like this:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword()
{
    return PartialView("_ChangePasswordPartial",...).WithTitle("Change Password");
}
```

**Extension method:**

```
public static IActionResult WithTitle(this IActionResult action, string modalTitle)
{
    return new ModalTitleDecorator(action,modalTitle);
}
```

**Decorator:**

```
public class ModalTitleDecorator : ActionResult
{
     private readonly IActionResult _actionResult;
     private readonly string _modalTitle;

     public ModalTitleDecorator(IActionResult action, string modalTitle)
     {
         _actionResult = action;
         _modalTitle = modalTitle;
     }

      public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
      {

          var tempData = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITempDataDictionaryFactory>()
                   .GetTempData(context.HttpContext);

         //always null...I assume that ViewData is not available according to HttpContext. 
         //TempData is available probably according to passing into next request.
         var viewData = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ViewDataDictionary>();

         //something like this would be great
         ViewData["Title"] = _modalTitle;

         await _actionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ViewData`, you could not resolve it by `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets <see cref="ViewDataDictionary"/> used by <see cref="ViewResult"/> and <see cref="ViewBag"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// By default, this property is intiailized when <see cref="Controllers.IControllerActivator"/> activates
/// controllers.
/// <para>
/// This property can be accessed after the controller has been activated, for example, in a controller action
/// or by overriding <see cref="OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)"/>.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// This property can be also accessed from within a unit test where it is initialized with
/// <see cref="EmptyModelMetadataProvider"/>.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
[ViewDataDictionary]
public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
```

As above statement, you only could access `ViewData` in `Controller` and `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)`. You could not access it by resolved service.

You could try to access `ViewData` by reflecting the `IActionResult`.

Try

```
public static class ActionResultExtension
{
    public static IActionResult WithTitle(this IActionResult action, string modalTitle)
    {
        return new ModalTitleDecorator(action, modalTitle);
    }
}

public class ModalTitleDecorator : PartialViewResult
{
    private readonly IActionResult _actionResult;
    private readonly string _modalTitle;

    public ModalTitleDecorator(IActionResult action, string modalTitle)
    {
        _actionResult = action;
        _modalTitle = modalTitle;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = _actionResult
                                    .GetType()
                                    .GetProperty("ViewData")
                                    .GetValue(_actionResult) as ViewDataDictionary;
        if (viewData != null)
        {
            viewData["Title"] = _modalTitle;
        }
        await _actionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: great, works perfectly. However, whats the performance of reflection? Is the overhead so small that I do not have to deal with it?

Comment: I get a null on .GetProperty("ViewData") in .net 5. Any ideas on how to solve this?